# Dampen operation sound in a sliding screen door

Tags: walls, doors, noise

I am doing college courses from home, and I live with somebody who will not stop slamming a sliding screen door. The screen door is located in the kitchen, there is a bathroom just north of it, and then my room is just north of the bathroom. The kitchen, bathroom, and my bedroom all share the west exterior wall of the house. The sound travels down the exterior wall into my bedroom, and it can be quite jarring. It has even woken me up at times. It is about 40 feet between the screen door and the wall where my bedroom starts. Is there something I can put in my bedroom to help dampen the noise from this screen door?

Comment: Have you considered placing some foam weather stripping in the channel where the door slides into?

Comment: Have you considered a high voltage circuit passing through the door handle?

Comment: In your bedroom I doubt it. In the door, more likely.

Comment: What kind of sliding screen door is this? A roll up model that's magnetically connected to the door frame when closed, and draws itself open when released, or some sort of rigid model that literally slides sideways in its entirety? Can you provide photos?

Comment: @JACK If the foam adds additional impedance to the closing/latching operation of the door then expect the noise to actually get louder.

Comment: Sliding door tracks are easy to sabotage if that's the route you wish to pursue. Once the door becomes hard to open then the person will likely stop using that door.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  I'm referring to the really thin weather stripping, 1/16" felt or similar.  When the door slams, it will be hitting a soft padding instead of a metal one.  the noise is from the slamming, not the closing.

Comment: It is not magnetically connected. It is completely free to slide. The latching mechanism on the door itself is broken and stuck in the open position, so we don't latch it anyway. We just slide it shut as far as it will go and leave it.

Comment: @JACK I'd be amazed if 1/16" of any material would make a difference.

Comment: I will look into getting some weather stripping. I think it might work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The weather strip idea is simple, I hope that works.  If not you could try

- A very thin dab of silicone caulk on the track about an inch from the end.  This will prevent the door sliding into the frame, you'll have to push it home.
- Here is [a company](https://arcdampers.com/small) that makes tiny dampers.     Sorry if I just planted an ear worm :). But seriously their motto is "We safely decelerate moving masses".  You could embed one of these in the door frame.
- There are a few vendors making soft close hardware for sliding or barn doors.  None of them are meant for screen doors that have their own seals on all four sides, but I think you could adapt one by screwing angle brackets to the top of the screen door, that reach up over the wall above where you would mount a rail with the soft close hardware.  It might look weird, I don't know.  Some of these are very expensive but not all.

Answer (score 0):

They make door closers that will slow the closing speed of the door and eliminate the slaming noise if adjusted properly. These can be purchased at your local box store for about $15 in the US.

Comment: For sliding doors?

Comment: *Dampen sound from a slamming screen door* +1. ... *I live with somebody who will not stop slamming a sliding screen door* belongs on IPS.SE